# ruby on rails one model multiple assocations with another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, associations, has-many

What would be the right (Rails) way to have one model with both a `has_many` and a `has_one` relationship? In my case, I want my `Device` model to keep track of both its current location and all of its previous locations.
This is my attempt and it is functional but is there a better way?

## Models

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :device
end

class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations # all previous locations
  belongs_to :location # current location
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :device
end

class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :locations

  def previous_locations
    self.locations.order('created_at asc').limit( self.locations.count-1)
  end

  def current_location # or last_location
    self.locations.order('created_at desc').limit(1)
  end

  # you may like to add this one
  def current_location= args
    args = Location.new args unless args.is_a? Location
    self.locations << args
  end
end
```

Note that all @device.locations, @device.previous_locations, and @device.current_location will return ActiveRecord::Relation

Answer (score 0):

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :locations
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Rails way is that you can create many associations you like. You can name your associations as well based on your logic. Simply pass the `:class_name` option to your association logic.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :device
end

class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :previous_locations,
           :class_name => "Location",
           :conditions => ["locations.created_at < ?", DateTime.now]
  has_one  :location,
           :class_name => "Location",
           :conditions => ["locations.created_at = ?", DateTime.now]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the "Guide to Active Record Associations", I recommend reading section 2.8: Choosing Between has_many :through and has_and_belongs_to_many

> The simplest rule of thumb is that you should set up a has_many
>   :through relationship if you need to work with the relationship model
>   as an independent entity. If you don’t need to do anything with the
>   relationship model, it may be simpler to set up a
>   has_and_belongs_to_many relationship (though you’ll need to remember
>   to create the joining table in the database).
>
> You should use has_many :through if you need validations, callbacks,
>   or extra attributes on the join model.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many

Answer (score 0):

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :device
  has_one :current_location, :class_name => 'Device',
                              :conditions => { :active => true }
end

class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations # all previous locations
end
```

Location has a boolean field called 'active' that you set to true/false.